# Is the effect of a power limited by the power's range?

Tags: dnd-4e

Last weekend my party ran into a scary "body-swap artifact" problem and my character wound up in the warlock's body... but that's a different story! `:)`.

Anyway, I got to use a number of warlock powers that I've never seen or used before. One was **Lure of Gibbeth** which I had cast on an opponent who was running away near the end of combat.  It has an effect line that read:

> Effect: Until the end of the encounter, you can
>   pull the target 2 squares as a minor
>   action once during your turn.

The power is `Ranged 10`. In the text in the PHB under Effect (pg 59) I didn't see anything to that limited it to the power's range in general and the power's text also had nothing specific to this end.

So: **Is the power's pull effect only usable while the target is within 10 squares?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say no. Most spells with a range limitation say so in the powers' effect line (I'm thinking largely of swordmage teleports). You need to be within 10 squares to tag the target with the power initially, after that they can wander wherever they want to.

Note that if the monster actually gets away while under the effect of that power, the encounter still officially "ends" after five minutes or during the next short rest. You don't get to pull them towards you for the rest of their life :)

Comment: Also note that you must still have line of effect to the target in order to pull it, and also for each square which you want the target pulled to.  An example of a power specifying the range of its persistent effect is "Hand of Caution", which allows you to push 1 when the target is within 5.

Comment: @iszi Where do you get the need for line of effect from?

Comment: @AceCalhoon "Forced Movement" entry in D&DI Compendium.

Comment: @Iszi Nice catch. It looks like this is also covered on page 285 of the PHB. I note the PHB states that you need line of effect to the *squares the target moves into* rather than the target... Is the Compendium entry the same?

Comment: @AceCalhoon The Compendium entry is the same.  However, I'm certain (can't find in the Compendium - will consult tomes at home) there's a more general rule that would cover line of effect to the target's square.

Comment: @AceCalhoon The most applicable bit of rules text I can find is in the Rules Compendium, page 107, under "Choosing a Target - Line of Effect":  *"Unless otherwise noted, there must be line of effect from the origin square of an effect and its intended target for that target to be affected."*  I think it would be generally agreed that even after the initial attack, the caster still remains as the "origin square" of most powers involving forced movement.  Therefore, if the caster wishes to make use of the effect, there must be line of effect at the time it is used.